# What's a good alternative to Neaman's book on semiconductors?

Tags: solid-state-physics, resource-recommendations, semiconductor-physics, electrical-engineering

So I'm an EE major taking a course for engineers on introductory semiconductor physics. It's  an online course with no live lectures so I'm essentially trying to teach myself, which isn't going very well because we're using Neaman's book and the style just doesn't work for me AT ALL.  There's so much focus on algebraic derivations with too little explanation of how the author knew to do the steps he did in the derivations and too little explanation of the concepts.  The thought that keeps coming to mind is, "he keeps missing the forest for the trees".

I'm at the point where, if I can't find a better book, I think I'm gonna have to drop the course, which I really don't want to do, for several reasons, unless it's absolutely necessary, so I'd really like some recommendations on good alternative texts.

I'm looking for something that

1. Gives good high and low level explanations of the important concepts, ideally using analogies to make things easier to understand and more intuitive. In particular, I like to be able to easily form mental pictures relating to the material, as that greatly improves my ability to remember it. Neaman's text, where it does give explanations, almost always quickly dives right into the technical details without any sort of big picture explanation to provide a jumping off point.  That just isn't working for me.
2. Effectively explains any non-obvious steps of the derivations in words.
   To be clear, I have no problem with math in general or algebra specifically, but I also think good mathematical communication doesn't rely solely or even necessarily *primarily* on algebraic manipulations, and I feel that Neaman's text is *far* too reliant on algebraic manipulations with no explanation of how he knew to do the manipulations he did.
3. Makes it clear which equations are the most important to each chapter/concept so I have an easier time solving problems because I know which equations to reference for each type of problem.
4. Ideally is available as a non-pirated eBook.  Unfortunately, I suffer from chronic neck and shoulder pain that's exacerbated if I spend long periods of time with my head bent downward.  Hence, heavy textbooks present a problem because they're too heavily to comfortably hold in front of my face, necessitating that I look downward to read them.  As a result, I always buy the eBook versions of textbooks, even though they're usually more expensive than buying a used physical copy.  One book that was came up a few times in my Googling for a good text on semiconductors was Pierret's, which, unfortunately, doesn't seem to be available as an ebook.  SWE's was also mentioned a couple places but also doesn't seem to be available as an ebook.

I did find this one on Amazon: https://a.co/4tg8reD

Judging from the free sample, it seems pretty good, but the sample only has up to chapter 3, which is on crystal structures, and I actually didn't mind Neaman's explanation of that topic too much either, because it's a comparatively simple topic, and things didn't start going downhill until the more advanced topics (so currently, we're on the second half of chapter 4 and the first half of chapter 5).  So I'm hesitant to spend the money on this one just because the crystal structures chapter seems good, as we're already past that content and I didn't have much trouble understanding it, as it was mostly just review from chem 102 anyway.

Also, on a side note, sometimes when I ask for book recommendations people instead recommend free online lecture playlists instead.  While I appreciate the thought, unfortunately I can rarely focus on lecture videos for a significant period of time and I get rather anxious and overwhelmed at the thought of trying to get through a bunch of lectures.  Hence, I really need a book or other written resource.